# Instancias SQL de un servidor remoto

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

El problema es el siguiente, querria obtener un listado de todas las instancias sql de un servidor remoto, actualmente solo he sido capaz de conseguir el listado a nivel local mediante el siguiente fragmento de código que aporta Microsoft.

```
class Program {  
  static void Main()  
  {  
    // Retrieve the enumerator instance and then the data.  
    SqlDataSourceEnumerator instance = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance;  
    System.Data.DataTable table = instance.GetDataSources();  
    // Display the contents of the table.  
    DisplayData(table);  
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue.");  
    Console.ReadKey();  
  }  
  private static void DisplayData(System.Data.DataTable table)  
  {  
    foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in table.Rows)  
    {  
      foreach (System.Data.DataColumn col in table.Columns)  
      {  
        Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", col.ColumnName, row[col]);  
      }  
      Console.WriteLine("============================");  
    }  
  }  
}
```

Para realizarlo en remoto, como sería?

Comment: Por favor [edit] la pregunta y agregue la fuente de información de Microsoft que menciona. Describa también qué problemas y/o errores tiene con este código.

Comment: a ese servidor remoto puedes conectarte desde el management studio? recuerda que por defecto Sql Server no expone los servicio a la red debes habilitarlo, quizas no lo lista porque no esta disponible para acceder desde la red